# Chrome localhost cookies not being set

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

I'm setting up ASP.NET Core authentication in different configurations, using Google Chrome as a development and test tool. Everything worked fine locally, but suddenly it stopped.

I've inspected the http headers and I found `Set-Cookie` one there in my `POST` response, but nothing in the next request nor in the Application->Storage->Cookies tab. I've inspected the console and found no errors nor warnings there. I've restated and updated Chrome (with no effect) and finally switched to Edge and then Firefox.

And, yes, I've searched whole the Internet, looking for the solution, but the highest ranked answers for similar issues are 5+ years old, `CORS` or `SameSite` related. Only once I found the [reference](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211#c73) to the **bug** in Chrome causing the issue I faced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem was a [bug in Google Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843371):

> If you have a secure cookie with same name set by  https://localhost, your cookie will fail to be set, **and you will not know that one exists unless you visit the page from https://localhost.**

In my case I've just once called my authentication service via `https`, and that silently blocked all the following attempts with `http`. Additionally annoying thing is that restarting Chrome does not clear that (session) cookies, so the behavior persists until manual cleanup, or starting an incognito window.

Comment: I apparently had this issue pop up and I didn't even know. Spent 2 hours debugging all my apps and trying to figure out why all authentication stopped working. Cleared browsing data and all works again.